# Open Drag/Dropped Excel File w/ .vbs and apply VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

Trying to open an Excel file that I drag and drop onto a .vbs script as below:

```
Wscript.echo "Begin..." 

Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments   dropped file
Wscript.echo "The file name you dropped is:" & objArgs(0)
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "objArgs(0)"
Wscript.echo "...Finished"
```

The line that results an error is `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "objArgs(0)"`

How to make the vbs code open it and then apply a macro to that Excel file?

Comment: remove the quotation marks: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run objArgs(0)`

Comment: `o=createobject("excel.application"):o.workbooks.open(objargs(0)):o.run "macro"`

Comment: It works. But is there a way to apply a vba code onto this opened sheet as well?

Comment: Open a workbook which has the macro you want to run, then call it using `objExcel.Run`   - see https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm   Or if your macro isn't very complex you could consider converting it to vbscript